# Is it Possible to Delete AWS S3 Objects Based on Object Size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, aws-java-sdk

I don't seem to find any document about deleting S3 objects based on the object size. For example if an object size is less that 5B then delete it.

Comment: Is this a one-off task, or do you want to do this every time that an object is created?

Comment: I need to do this every time an object it uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, it appears you want to delete objects immediately after creation if they are smaller than a given size.

To do this, you would:

- Create an **AWS Lambda function**
- Configure the S3 bucket to **trigger** the Lambda function when an object is created

The Lambda function will be passed the Bucket and Key of the object(s) that was/were just created. It can then call `HeadObject` to obtain the size of the object. If it is smaller than the desired size, it can then call `DeleteObject`. Make sure to loop through all passed-in Records because one Lambda function can be invoked with multiple input objects.

If you have **existing objects** on which you wish to perform this operation, and since you mentioned that there are "over 1 million objects", you could use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects, including their size. You can write a program that uses this file as input and the calls `DeleteObjects` to delete up to 1000 objects at a time.

Comment: I was thinking of the same process but I’m new to AWS and it really helps to confirm I’m in the right track from an expert like you. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to delete an S3 Object based on size.

One workaround is to get the Object size of the S3 bucket via AWS CLI ( you can use cli or boto3 ) and performing a **cron** job that will perform the condition when **true** if the object size is less than 5B.

Comment: This will require to loop through all objects in the bucket. What I need is to check the size of the only new uploaded object. Based on  @John Rotenstein, it looks like this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The `DeleteObject()` API call does not accept parameters such as Size or ModifiedDate.

Instead, you must provide a list of object(s) to be deleted.

If you wish to delete objects based on their size, the typical pattern would be:

- Call `ListObjets()` to obtain a listing of objects in the bucket (and optionally in a given prefix)
- In your code, loop through the returned information and example the object size. Where the size is smaller/larger than desired, add the `Key` (filename) to an array
- Call `DeteleObject()`, passing the array of Keys to be deleted

Comment: Won't this cost a lot of money listing a bucket with over 1 million objects? I was looking for something that gets triggered on new uploaded objects only not the whole bucket.

Comment: You never mentioned the size of your bucket. You also didn't mention that you'd like it triggered on new uploads. It would be helpful if you put complete information in your question.

Comment: You’re right. I should’ve mentioned those details on the question.